# Выбор точки появления в Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity3d

Пытаюсь сделать переключение места появления(transform) в одном моём проекте. Выглядеть это должно так: в главном меню игры игрок выбирает точку появления (при помощи toggle), после чего скрипт сохраняет через PlayerPrefs.SetInt число, которое обозначает номер transforma для того, чтобы получить этот инт в другой сцене. И тут у меня возникает проблема: не знаю, как сделать, чтобы в другой сцене скрипт, "принимающий" это число спавнил игрока на выбранной точке. Пробовал сделать через if, но получил ошибку, т.к. это переменная int, а не bool.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class CarLoad : MonoBehaviour
{
[SerializeField] private Transform _carPos1;
[SerializeField] private Transform _carPos2;
public GameObject _car1;

void Start()
{
    PlayerPrefs.GetInt("LocNum");
}


void Update()
{
    if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("LocNum", 1))
    {
        Instantiate(_car1, _carPos1.position, _carPos1.rotation);
    }
}
}
```

Или есть какой-нибудь другой вариант?

Подскажите, как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: [PlayerPrefs.HasKey()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.HasKey.html) Зачем вы инстанциируете игрока в Update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("LocNum", 1) == 1)
```

А еще лучше

```
int locNum = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("LocNum", 1)
switch (locNum)
      {
      case 1:
          Instantiate(_car1, _carPos1.position, _carPos1.rotation);
          break;
      case 2:
          Instantiate(_car1, _carPos2.position, _carPos2.rotation);
          break;
      default:
          //Действие при невалидных данных
          Instantiate(_car1, _carPos1.position, _carPos1.rotation);
          break;
  }
```

И конечно `Instantiate` надо сделать один раз, например, в `Start`.